# Convert from Netty 4.0 CR3 to 4.0.10-final

Tags: java, netty

I am upgrading my frameworks Netty version to the newest and it seems that the API has broke (I know I shouldn't have used it until a final version was out); I have been reading over the docs and looking through classes to try and find a feasible solution but I cannot find one.

```
    ctx.nextInboundMessageBuffer().add(message);
    ctx.fireInboundBufferUpdated();

    if (additionalBuf != null) {
        ChannelHandlerContext head = ctx.pipeline().firstContext();
        head.nextInboundByteBuffer().writeBytes(additionalBuf);
        head.fireInboundBufferUpdated();
    }
```

Is what I am trying to convert to the new API, any help is appreciated.

Full code:

```
@Override
protected void decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf in, List<Object> out) throws Exception {
    if (!in.isReadable()) {
        return;
    }

    int messageId = in.readUnsignedByte();

    ByteBuf additionalBuf = null;
    if (in.isReadable()) {
        additionalBuf = in.readBytes(in.readableBytes());
    }

    ChannelPipeline pipeline = ctx.pipeline();
    pipeline.remove(HandshakeDecoder.class);

    HandshakeMessage message = HandshakeMessage.forId(messageId);

    switch (message) {
    case LOGIN_MESSAGE:
        break;
    case UPDATE_MESSAGE:
        break;
    default:
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected message id: " + messageId);
    }

    ctx.nextInboundMessageBuffer().add(message);
    ctx.fireInboundBufferUpdated();

    if (additionalBuf != null) {
        ChannelHandlerContext head = ctx.pipeline().firstContext();
        head.nextInboundByteBuffer().writeBytes(additionalBuf);
        head.fireInboundBufferUpdated();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what "broke" means? (And does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16469072/migrating-sendupstream-in-netty-4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's explained here:

http://netty.io/news/2013/06/18/4-0-0-CR5.html

In general you just would use fireChannelRead(...)